# React front-end app on nginx server cannot reach the nodejs back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my first React, Node, MongoDB, Nginx app on EC2 free tire. backend API is working separately and front-end also running well. but front end API calls don't reach each other.

front end: http://18.130.30.219/
node API: http://18.130.30.219:5000/api/article/thumbist

default.conf as below

```
server {
#listen       80;
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  localhost;

access_log /home/ubuntu/client/server_logs/host.access.log main;

location / {
    root   /home/ubuntu/client/deploy;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

server_tokens off;

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

I came across a solution.

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
```

lines have to be added into default.conf file.

if your API uses different port and/or route (Eg:'/api'), you have to configure it as above. I'm just a very beginner for MERN stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config API url in frontend code
`Request URL: http://18.130.30.219/api/article/create`, It is calling to frontend url.

Comment: yes.. it is requesting in a deferent port (80) it should be port 5000
Request URL: http://18.130.30.219/api/user/login
but I have this 
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" in package.json